# How to show if this function satisfies the wave equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

If F and G have second partial derivatives, show that $U(x,t)=F(x+at)+G(x-at)$ satisfies the wave equation:
$$a^{2}\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}$$.
Sol: $$\\$$
I first say that $s=x+at$ and $w=x-at$, then i try to use the chain rule $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial U}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}$$
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial (F+G)}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial (F+G)}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}$$
For propierties: 
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial s} \right) \frac{\partial s}{\partial t}+ \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial w}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial w} \right)\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}$$
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=a\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial s} \right) - a\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial w}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial w} \right)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}=a\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial s} \right) - a\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial w}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial w} \right)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}=a\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial t\partial s}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial t\partial s} \right) - a\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial t\partial w}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial t\partial w} \right)$$

I do not know what to do in this part. I appreciate help.

Comment: @Mattos a error. sorry.

Comment: With $s = x + at$, $w = x - at$, by the chain rule

\begin{align}
u_{x} &= \frac{dF}{ds} \cdot \partial_{x} s + \frac{dG}{dw} \cdot \partial_{x} w \\
&= F' \cdot 1 + G' \cdot 1 \\
&= F' + G' \\
\implies u_{xx} &= \partial_{x} (F' + G') \\
&= \partial_{x} F' + \partial_{x} G' \\
&= \frac{dF'}{ds} \cdot \partial_{x} s + \frac{dG'}{dw} \cdot \partial_{x} w \\
&= F'' + G''
\end{align}

Now use this to do your $t$ derivatives. Also, from this, can you see where you went wrong? (Hint: In your attempt, what do $dF/dw$ and $dG/ds$ equal?)

Answer (score 2):

Good start. It looks like you're having some bookkeeping issues. I think in this case it may be easier to not wrap $x+at$ and $x-at$ as separate variables. Note that $F$ and $G$ are both functions of *one* variable, the mixing of the variables happens in the $x\pm at$ arguments. Let's see how it goes.

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} U(x,t) &= F'(x+at)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x+at) + G'(x-at)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x-at)\\
&= aF'(x+at) - aG'(x-at)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}U(x,t) &= F'(x+at)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+at) + G'(x-at)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-at)\\
&= F'(x+at) + G'(x-at).
\end{align*}
Can you take the next set of derivatives from here?

Comment: In a beginning i started solving the exercise like you, but in a moment i get: $$\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}=a^2 \left(\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial t^2} \right)$$ How i can get: $$\left(\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial t^2} \right)=\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}$$

Comment: @testpilot That's not what you need to show! You need to show that $a^2U_{xx} = U_{tt}$.

Comment: @testpilot Also note that $F$ and $G$ are functions of a single variable --- that's why I used the notation $F'$ and $G'$ to denote their derivatives.